# writing to firestore after authenticating

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, es6-promise

Im creating a react native application using expo and I'm currently trying to connect the firestore database to the application. When I run this in a function it doesn't write to the database but it does create a authenticated user.

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((result) => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(result.user.uid)
            .set({ uid: result.user.uid });
     })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I found a way around this so that it does write to the database but wasn't sure if this is an acceptable way

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithCredential(credential)
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        console.log('adding to db');
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .doc(user.uid)
            .set({ uid: user.uid });
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
    }
```

Any advice is appreciated !
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but wasn't sure if this is an acceptable way

This is not only acceptable, but it's currently the right way.  The problem is that the Firebase Auth SDK doesn't set the current user before the promise resolves from the call to `signInWithCredential`.  Without a current user set, the Firestore SDK doesn't know what credentials to use for a query.  However, when `onAuthStateChanged` delivers a user object, you know for certain that the current is user is set.